# Logging out of facebook with server side sdk without revoking permissions

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, logout

I am building a site in php which uses facebook login to grant access. When the user logs out I want to log them out of facebook as well as my app. I have looked everywhere to find out how to do this but there is nothing out there apart from a tutorial the facebook developer page that explains how to log the user out while also revoking the permissions they granted you when they logged in. I dont want to do this, I just want to log the user out of my app and facebook without revoking permissions. Is this possible with the server side sdk?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the PHP SDK, you can use it as described in the following link :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/